# In how many ways can 5 chocolates be chosen from an unlimited number of Cadbury, Five-star, and Perk chocolates?

Tags: permutations, combinations

This might be trivial but I am still confused about it. I am having some trouble in interpreting this question. My approach was to simply convert the question into the equation

$$a + b + c = 5$$

where $a,b,c$ represent the number of Cadbury,Five-star, and Perk chocolates. The number of solutions to the above equation is

${5+3-1 \choose 3-1}$

which is $21$.

But the book is taking the approach that for each of the chocolates you have $3$ options. So the total number of ways in which this can be done is $3^5$ which is $243$.

Is that how the question should be interpreted? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it should be mentioned if order matters or not.

Comment: I guess, but does choose by itself say permutation? I do not want to have this confusion in an exam and hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's ambiguity over whether order matters or not. Your method gets the number of different ways when order doesn't matter; the book's answer assumes order matters. For example, if we denote a choice of Cadbury by C, Five-star by F, and Perk by P, your method assumes CCFFP is the same as FFCCP, while the book's method counts the two as distinct choices. It's probably best to ask your teacher/TA over which method they have in mind.

Comment: Thanks DylanSp. There is no teacher actually. I am preparing for am exam from a book while working. Such ambiguities are eating a lot of my time as I think I am doing something wrong for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

we have to choose five chocolates,say, f1, f2, f3, f4 and f5. Now for f1 we can choose among three kinds of chocolates.
Since the supply of chocolates is infinite, for f2, again we Can choose among three kinds of chocolates. 
Similarly for each of f3, f4, f5, we have three options.
So total number of choices =3^5=243.

Comment: OF course this solution assumes that order matters.